# How to get tbbmalloc_proxy on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, memory-management, tbb

Threading Building Blocks includes a thread local allocator in the form of `libtbbmalloc` (and `scalable_allocator`). For Linux and Windows they also offer a `libtbbmalloc_proxy` that can replace `malloc` and `new` with scalable versions simply by linking against it.

The official docs omit any mention of `libtbbmalloc_proxy` on OSX, and it also does not appear in the `lib` directory of the distribution. What is the canonical way to get a scalable `new` on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**: Global replacement of memory allocation routines for OS X is added into Intel Threading Building Blocks v4.3. You can do the replacement either by loading `libtbbmalloc_proxy.dylib` at program load time using the DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES environment variable, or by linking the main executable file with the proxy library. See [more details in the TBB User Guide](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/OS_X_C_Dynamic_Memory_Interface_Replacement.htm). Prior to 4.3, this functionality was unavailable for OS X.

---

The canonical way to replace `new` is to define your own version of it. By the C++ standard, the following routines declared in `<new>` should be defined in the global namespace:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t size);
void* operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete(void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
void* operator new[](std::size_t size);
void* operator new[](std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept;
```

By default, these functions are defined (implemented) in the language support library; but a program is allowed to redefine these functions. So you might implement these functions to use the TBB memory allocator, e.g.

```
void* operator new( std::size_t object_size )
{
    void* mem = scalable_malloc( object_size );
    if (mem==NULL) throw std::bad_alloc();
    return mem;
}
void* operator new(std::size_t object_size, const std::nothrow_t&) noexcept
{
    return scalable_malloc( object_size );
}
```

and etc.

See also:

- [How should I write ISO C++ Standard conformant custom new and delete operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators/)
- [Replacing libstdc++.dylib (4.0) global new and delete operators on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472020/replacing-libstdc-dylib-4-0-global-new-and-delete-operators-on-osx)

Comment: My project is a library (most of it is templates, but not all). Do I only have to define these operators in a .cpp/.o that gets linked in, or do they have to be declared in the headers like any other function?

Comment: These functions are declared in `<new>`, you do not need to re-declare them. I added a clarification to the answer.